# Why is it possible to instantiate multiple traits in Scala, but not a single one?

Tags: scala, inheritance, instantiation, multiple-inheritance, traits

Let's say we have two traits:

```
trait Trait1
trait Trait2
```

If I try something like `val single = new Trait1` I get an error `error: trait Trait1 is abstract; cannot be instantiated`. However, `val twoTraits = new Trait1 with Trait2` compiles. Why is it so?

P.S. I also observed that `val single = new Trait1 {}` compiles just fine. Could you provide a proper explanation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, you can't instantiate a single trait or multiple mixed traits directly, but the compiler uses some syntactic sugar that allows you to create *anonymous classes* that extend them. Let's say we have:

```
trait A
trait B
```

When you call `new A with B`, what's really happening is that the compiler is creating an anonymous class that mixes in both `A` and `B`. You get:

```
final class $anon extends A with B
new $anon()
```

When you call `new A {}`, the same thing happens. You get an anonymous class that extends `A`:

```
final class $anon extends A
new $anon()
```

The only difference is syntactical. When creating an anonymous class from a single trait, you are required to at least use braces `{}` to distinguish it from a class. That is, it is easier to discern whether the template can be constructed, or must be wrapped in an anonymous class to be constructed. With multiple traits (or even a class with traits mixed in), the compiler understands it will *always* need to create an anonymous class first.

To summarize:

```
class C

new A {}       // Anonymous class that extends A, then constructed
new A with B   // Anonymous class that extends A with B, then constructed
new C          // Constructed instance of class C
new C with A   // Anonymous class that extends C with A, then constructed
```

Comment: `trait A extends C; new A with B` means `new C with A with B`. Rule for adding a class if with clause starts with a trait: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates